# ggplot2: mean and median in geom_violin

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, median

I was plotting a violin plot and mean and median values as follows:

```
test <- read.csv2("http://www.reduts.net/test.csv", sep=",")

ggplot(data = test, aes(y = var, x = as.factor(grp))) +
  geom_violin() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 23, size = 2)+
  stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", size = 2, color = "red")+
  xlab("Group") +
  ylab("EUR") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1000), breaks = seq(0,1000,200))+
  ggsave("image.jpg", dpi = 300, units = 'cm', height = 10, width = 22)

library(psych)
describe(test$var)
```

Now, my problem is that all the group-means displayed in the image are far lower than the mean I get when using `psych::describe()` over all groups.

Is it possible, that the means and medians computed for each group do not include the outliers in each group (only the values within the whiskers)? And if so, how can I plot the "real" medians/means for all data points?

Comment: If you can't post data, we can't help.

Comment: Create a dummy data set that could mimic your dataset.

Comment: Certainly can't reproduce with `iris` dataset.

Comment: At least perhaps show the graph & give the code you are using with `describe` so we can see the mismatch - might help to determine the cause.

Comment: I've anonymised the data now (see above)

Comment: Note also `describe(test$var)` doesn't give a description split up by group but rather the overall mean etc, so will not match up with the graph (which splits by group) anyway.

Comment: Yes, but the overall-mean/median cannot be higher than all the group-means/medians

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `scale_y_continuous(limits=)` filters the underlying data, so the mean/median in stat_summary are of the pre-filtered data.

To simply zoom in without changing the underlying data, use `coord_cartesian`

e.g.

```
+ coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 1000))
```

---

Here is a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() +
    stat_summary(fun.y='mean', geom='point', size=2, col='red')
p
# mean(subset(iris, Species == 'setosa')$Sepal.Length) # 5.006
```

Note that the average Sepal Length for setosa is about 5.
now let's limit the y axis.

```
p + scale_y_continuous(lim=c(5, 8), minor_breaks=seq(5, 8, by=0.1))
Warning messages:
1: Removed 22 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
2: Removed 22 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Note the warning messages, and see that in the resulting plot the average Sepal Length for setosa is now a bit more than 5.2.
To confirm the `scale_y_continuous` is indeed filtering the data before calculating the `stat_summary`,

```
mean(subset(iris, Species == 'setosa' & Sepal.Length >= 5)$Sepal.Length)
# 5.23
```

whereas if I just do

```
p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(5, 8))
```

the means are as they were on the original data. (You can still use `scale_y_continuous` for the breaks, just don't use the limits).

Comment: Does scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(min, MAX, step)) also filter?

Comment: Try and see. (no; if your MAX is much lower than the ylim then you simply won't have any breaks between MAX and ylim)